# Gradle panel shows dependencies rather than tasks

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

Have this issue in a KMM project where I cannot see that available gradle tasks in the gradle panel but rather, I see the dependencies.

I am running Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Canary 15 which is the latest. Have tried deleting the .idea folder and also invalidating and restart. Still shows up the same.

[image]

Comment: I get the same problem when I open the `android/` project in a React Native app. Android Studio version is the latest stable release (4.2.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Android Studio 4.2.* the task list is not build during gradle sync for performance reason.

You should uncheck the box in the experimental features here:

[image]